# Facebook Comments Moderation Tool

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I am having a website built and within this we are using the Facebook Comments plugin.  Obviously, we'd like to moderate the comments on there.  So, we have set up with an AppID and followed all the steps to get Comments and moderation setup but, for some reason the moderation tool isn't connecting with the comments plugin.  How do we solve this?

The website in development is at http://goalfrenzy.dev.fluid-dev.co.uk/

Comment: Please edit your post to show the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the problem. What have you tried so far?